# definition of $T^*M$

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, tangent-bundle

My teacher didn't define $T^*M$ in the course. I was wondering what it was.

I suppose that it is

$$T^*M := \bigsqcup_{p\in M}T^*_pM := \bigsqcup_{p\in M}(T_pM)^*$$

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotangent_bundle) has a page about it, if that helps.

Comment: I think the real subtlety that you should worry about is how to show that it is a manifold by introducing an atlas on it. As a set, it seems that you're right. But what atlas do you have in mind to show that it's a manifold? Just saying. Basically, how does a differential form written in two different coordinates transform? That's what you should focus on, I guess.